# error: Unexpected strict mode reserved word when using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios, react-hooks

I am using react to write a demo here:
[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-examples-jjzjx)
I know there is something wrong with the `await` and `async` method. but I don't know why. 
it went fine if using `aixos.get().` then individually, but if I wrapped it in a class and use it with a custom hook in `useEffect`, it throws me

> Unexpected strict mode reserved word

Comment: I know that `axiosManager.fetchMockData();` is the problem but i couldn't figured out why, i think you should try playing around inside `axiosManager`, that might solve it

Comment: Please post the code that causes the error

Comment: @Bergi , I have added the link : [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-examples-jjzjx-swjd5k) , it can describe the problem better.

Comment: @jjzjx118_2 No, please [post the code, not just a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Answer (score 0):

in your axiosManager the key word `async` must be written before the function not the variable containing the function so change

```
async const fetchMockData = () =>{
      const rst = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
      return rst;
  }
```

to

```
const fetchMockData = async () =>{
      const rst = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
      return rst;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried but still not work. can you please edite my code in that demo?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the reason if you can't use await inside useEffect directly, because it's not an async method. so we can change it to this :

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const manager = new AxiosManager();
    let rst = await manager.fetchMockData();
    console.log(rst);
  };

  // effect_fechData();
  useEffect(() => {   
    fetchData();
  });
```

api manager:

```
export default class AxiosManager {

   async fetchMockData () {
      const rst = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
      return rst;
  }


};
```